# css layout menu navigation bar doesn't dsiplay horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am writing a simple navigation bar with horizontal display. I applied display: inline; to the li element in the CSS below but doesn't seem working. The whole menu is currently vertical displayed.

Any help is very appreciated.

```
<div class="header-nav-bar">
            <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">home1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">AAAA</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">BBBB</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home4</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">cccc</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dddd</a></li> 
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home5</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div> 



.header-nav-bar
{
Position: relative;
background-color: #FFDB38;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

.header-nav-bar  a{
display: block;
}

.navbar
{
postion: relative;
width:50%;
overlow: auto;
margin: auto;
}

.navbar ul ul{
display: none;
}

.navbar ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar ul li:hover ul{
display: block;
background-color: #FF7F00;
}

.navbar li
{
display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `<a>` inside your `<li>` have `display: block;` and thus expand your `<li>` to the maximum width.

If you need to make sure your links have a certain width, for example 90px, just set them to `display: inline-block;` and `width: 90px;`.

```
.header-nav-bar  a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use  `display: inline-block;` for `.navbar ul > li`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-nav-bar
{
Position: relative;
background-color: #FFDB38;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

.header-nav-bar  a{
display: block;
}

.navbar
{
postion: relative;
width:50%;
overlow: auto;
margin: auto;
}

.navbar ul ul{
display: none;
}

.navbar ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}
.navbar ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
.navbar ul li:hover ul{
display: block;
background-color: #FF7F00;
    position: absolute; top: 15px; left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-nav-bar">
            <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">home1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">AAAA</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">BBBB</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home4</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">cccc</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">dddd</a></li> 
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home5</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Even though this solves the problem, it does not explain what causes the unwanted behaviour. For an explanation (and the real fix for the root problem), see my answer below.

Comment: thanks for the answer! just a quick question, what is '>'  in '.navbar ul > li' for. I deleted it and it looks the same.

Comment: It means that the `li` must be an immediate child of the `ul`. For example you might want to use an ordered list `<ol>` inside an `<li>` which also has `<li>` as children. `ul > li` will not target those, whereas `ul li`will. Does that answer your question? Otherwise it might be worth asking a new question on SO titling "What is the difference between `ul > li` and `ul li`?"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.navbar li
{
display: inline;
float:left;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1n4rfqf/)

Comment: That is not the solution, see my post below. Apart from causing all the problems involved with floating behaviour.